# Custom PAM fails at PAM_CONVERSATION in SSH

Tags: c, linux, ssh, pam

I've been trying to implement a custom **PAM** for 2nd Factor Verification. The Custom PAM needs to read factor selected(integer) and pass it on to the program. The below code works fine in **SUDO** and **SU** but I'm getting "***Connection Closed by host port 22***" error while trying with **SSH**. Can anyone help me sort the issue.

```
static char *request_pass(pam_handle_t *pamh, int echocode,PAM_CONST char *prompt) 
{
    // Query user for verification code
    PAM_CONST struct pam_message msg = { .msg_style = PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_ON,.msg = prompt };
    PAM_CONST struct pam_message *msgs = &msg;

    // PAM_CONST struct pam_message msg;
    struct pam_conv conv = {re,NULL};
    struct pam_response *resp = NULL;
    int retval = re(1,&msgs,&resp,"");
    return "";
}
```

```
int re(int nummsg,PAM_CONST struct pam_message **msg,struct pam_response **resp, void *appdata_ptr)
{
    *resp = malloc(sizeof(struct pam_response));
    assert(*resp);
    (*resp)->resp = calloc(1024,1);

    printf("%s^^ ", msg[0]->msg);
    fflush(stdout);
    assert(fgets((*resp)->resp, 1024, stdin));
    char *ret = NULL;
    ret = (*resp)->resp;
   

  // Deallocate temporary storage
    if (*resp) 
    {
        if (!ret) 
        {
            free((*resp)->resp);
        }
        free(*resp);
    }
    factorselect = atoi(ret);
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit: Below code worked for me(Solved)

```
char *
s_prompt(void *arg, const char *prompt, char *buf, size_t bufsz)
{
    char *p = NULL;

    if (pam_prompt((pam_handle_t *)arg, PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_ON, &p,
        "%s", prompt) != PAM_SUCCESS || p == NULL) {
        return (NULL);
    }
    strncpy(buf, p, bufsz);
    free(p);
    return (buf);
}
```

Comment: I haven't used PAM in a while, but I'm pretty sure that you shouldn't be accessing stdin/stdout as you are doing. You should probably be using `pam_prompt()`, or use the `pam_conv` acquired via `pam_get_item` directly. Unless I'm misunderstanding your purpose entirely, and you're making a PAM client rather than a module. You might want to look at an existing PAM module to see example usage.

Comment: Thanks for the response, `pam_prompt()` worked for ssh